# Retaining records in one text row based on keywords in another text row pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

The dataframe below has two text columns, **text** with sentences and **keyword** that has a list of keywords using which I want to filter the **text** column
[image]

I'm trying to filter the **text** on the condition of **keyword** column. If any of the words in the **keyword** column exist in **text** column, we retain that row and if not we drop it.

The output dataframe should look like this.
[image]

I tried using str.contains() function in pandas which is incorrect as contains() function is looking for regex/pattern.

```
df['text'].str.contains(df['keyword'].str)
```

I got the below error

```
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With builtin `any` function (to check if any of the list of *keywords* occurs within a *text*):

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: any(k in x.text for k in x.keyword), axis=1)]
```